# "undefined is not a function" using callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback

I'm creating a twitter bot that is requesting from the same API, Wordnik, but each request is depending on the last request's results. So, I decided to try creating some code using callbacks to make sure that all of the information is returned from the API before the next function runs. I am having trouble setting it up, I have looked at many examples and I just cannot get the hang of it. (Sorry for the messy code).

The error I am getting right now is "undefined is not a function" in my function getWord() on thenRunThisFunction(getRhyme). I'm wondering if I have a small error with the callbacks or if my whole approach to this problem is incorrect?

```
function runBot() {
var request = require('request');
var Twit = require('twit');
var async = require('async');
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '' // Your Consumer Key
  , consumer_secret:      '' // Your Consumer Secret
  , access_token:         '' // Your Access Token
  , access_token_secret:  '' // Your Access Token Secret
});

var WORDNIKAPIKEY = '';

// GLOBAL VARS
var randomWord; //get random word
var rhymingWord; //get rhyming word
var bogusDef; //get def of rhyming word
var tweet; // combined random and bogusdef 

function getWord(thenRunThisFunction){ 
    request('http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/words.json/randomWord?hasDictionaryDef=false&minCorpusCount=0&maxCorpusCount=-1&minDictionaryCount=1&maxDictionaryCount=-1&minLength=5&maxLength=-1&api_key=' + WORDNIKAPIKEY, function (error, response, body1) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //console.log(body1) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
        var pparsedData = JSON.parse(body1);
        console.log("Word: " + pparsedData.word);

        // set random word
        randomWord = pparsedData.word;
        thenRunThisFunction(getRhyme);
        }
    })
}

// Get the rhyming word
function getRhyme(thenRunThisFunction){
    request('http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/' + randomWord + '/relatedWords?useCanonical=false&relationshipTypes=rhyme&limitPerRelationshipType=10&api_key=' + WORDNIKAPIKEY, function (error, response, body2) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //console.log(body2) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
        var o = JSON.parse(body2);
        console.log("Rhyme: " + o[0].words[0]);

        // set rhyming word
        rhymingWord = o[0].words[0];
        thenRunThisFunction(getDef);
        }
    })
}

// GET THE SEXY DEFINITION BABY, BEACH BOD
function getDef(thenRunThisFunction){       
    request('http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/' + rhymingWord + '/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=true&sourceDictionaries=all&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=' + WORDNIKAPIKEY, function (error, response, body3) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //console.log(body3) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
        var newnew = JSON.parse(body3);
        console.log("Definition: " + newnew[0].text);

        // set definition 
        bogusDef = newnew[0].text;

        randomWord = randomWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        tweet = randomWord + ": " + bogusDef;
        thenRunThisFunction(postStatus);
        }
    })
}   

function postStatus(){
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: tweet }, function(err, data, response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("There was a problem tweeting the message.", err);
        }
    });
    console.log("status posted");
}
getWord();
}
runBot();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue really what you're trying to accomplish, instead of going

```
thenRunThisFunction();
thenRunThisFunction();
thenRunThisFunction();
thenRunThisFunction();
thenRunThisFunction();
```

Just invoke them by their names, remove the argument from them

```
getRhyme();
getDef();
```

What you're doing will never work, you're trying to call `thenRunThisFunction` as if it actually exists, it's an argument in your function that never gets served

Your method would work if it was like this:

```
function runThisFunction(fnc) {
  fnc();   
}

function blah(thenRunThisFunction) {
    thenRunThisFunction(thing);
}

function thing() {
  console.log('Blah');
}

blah(runThisFunction);
```

But that's horrible and bad.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that the first function finished before the next function gets called. This may have just been a bad post. I am really not understanding how to make sure that the API response is given before the next function starts.

Comment: @Ryan The fix is simple, just call the function by name, replace `thenRunThisFunction(getRhyme);` with `getRhyme();`

Comment: I just tried that. It's gets to the getRhyme() method and then gives the error: cannot read property "words" of undefined.

All of these requests work separately when the second two have hard coded info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79601/discussion-between-ryan-and-datsik).

Comment: @Ryan http://pastebin.com/V0bLG9bY , and if you're no longer getting undefined for the function, then your problem is solved and you should mark one of the answers here as the answer, and open a new question about why words cannot be read, which that error means that whatever object you're trying to read `words` from, does not have that property

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing a function reference into getWord().

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing anything to getWord at the end so thenRunThisFunction is literally undefined. Try passing a function to getWord like this getWord(function(){}). But in your case you want to pass whatever you want to run after get word.